# Opening Stack Exchange app from web browser link onto SE site eliminates my draft for that site

Tags: feature-request, bug

I currently opened a link to a Stack Overflow post from Chrome on Android and it brought me to my account on the Stack Exchange app on the Stack Overflow page. It eliminated the draft I had which I wanted to post on Stack Overflow. This is not certainly a bug.

Could it be fixed in future versions of the app?

Comment: The mobile app and the website have different draft systems. When you go back to Chrome is your draft still there?

Comment: I didn't login from chrome. Just Google searched my username, opened the link, for automatically logged in, and the draft from the stack exchange app got blanked out.